# Show database columns as headers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very strange situation and need expert opinion that is there any solution available or should i change my database structure.

### Test Tables

```
ID    TestName
1       HP
2       PV
3       UX
```

### Patient Test Records

```
ID    PID    TestName     TestValues        Date
1      2       HP            23          12-11-2017
2      2       PV            88          12-11-2017
3      5       UX            24          14-11-2017
4      5       HP            44          14-11-2017
5      2       UX            33          15-11-2017
```

### Expected Output for each patient

```
TestName   PId    12-11-2017    15-12-2017
   HP       2        23            -
   PV       2        88            -
   UX       2        -            33
```

Now should I restructure my DB and is there any solution in MSSQL.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did you try to build a query?

Comment: Looks like you want to investigate PIVOT/UNPIVOT ... turn column values into column headers and vice-versa (rows into columns, columns into rows).

Comment: Look for dynamic pivot.

Comment: I tried to use PIVOT but in my case patient visit dates are dynamic so not sure how to figure it out.

Comment: That's why @SQLChao said *dynamic* pivot...

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([date]) from #patientdata where pid = 2 for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = ' Select * from 
    ( Select PID, TestName, TestValues, [Date] from #patientdata where pid = 2) a
    pivot (max(TestValues) for [date] in (' + @cols1 + ') ) p '

Exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Output as below:

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| PID | TestName | 2017-11-12 | 2017-11-15 |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
|   2 | HP       | 23         | NULL       |
|   2 | PV       | 88         | NULL       |
|   2 | UX       | NULL       | 33         |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind reply. It works like a charm but having issue when i tried to execute this query in SQL CE as i am using compact edition.